# CSS is not working in FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox

The main issue is the following. All images are showing as broken links in FireFox and they are fine in other browsers like Safari, Opera and Chrome.

Then I contacted the support they said it is known issue with CSS when it comes to FireFox.

Here is my CSS code

```
      <head>
<title>My Booklet</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
  html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  body {
    background-color: transparent;
    -moz-transform: perspective(1400px) matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  .gwd-table-5il4 {
    background-image: none;
    -moz-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  .gwd-tr-qiqz {
    background-image: none;
  }

.fadein { position:relative; height:335px; width:223px; }
.fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function blink() {
    var blinks = document.getElementsByTagName('blink');
    for (var i = blinks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       var s = blinks[i];
      s.style.visibility = (s.style.visibility === 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
    }
    window.setTimeout(blink, 700);
  }
  if (document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", blink, false);
  else if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("load", blink, false);
  else if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", blink);
  else window.onload = blink;
</script>    

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first-    child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 3000);
});
</script>
```

Appreciate any help on this.

I have added some additional script that I am using. the rest of the HTML file is sort of basic html tag for tables, images, and URLs.

Regards,

Comment: change your prefix to `-moz`
-webkit prefixes are safari and chrome

Comment: Could you provide additional HTML-Code so we can test it?

Comment: Add properties with mozkit too

Comment: Still not working I have removed the property completely. it seems it is not the issue.

Comment: It's the space in `:first-    child`

Comment: Without an example that shows the problem, we are not able to help.

Answer (score 5):

`-webkit` is a prefix for Chrome and Safari, it has no effects on Firefox. Firefox one is `-moz`

Try to add -moz prefixes like :

```
/* Chrome and Safari */
-webkit-transform: perspective(1400px) matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: perspective(1400px) matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

/* Other */
transform: perspective(1400px) matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

Edit: Add no prefixed properties as Volvox pointed out

Comment: Important thing to remember is to ALWAYS add not prefixed version too for other browsers.

Comment: You don't need to remove code, you need to add code!

Comment: I mean I have added "-moz" the code and it didn't work. Then, I have removed the code for both -webkit and -moz completely and still didn't work

Answer (score 2):

For firefox

```
Add properties with -moz too 

-webkit is only for chrome and safari
```

for example

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

Answer (score 0):

webkit is for google chrome and safari, firefox don't understand this. It use `-moz`....
like -`moz-border-radius`
You have to check if firefox can support these functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The first-child has a space in it. Otherwise it works

### Old

```
$(function(){
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first-    child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 3000);
});
```

### New

```
$(function(){
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 3000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nZFnS/

Comment: Hi, The space came here when I copy past.
The original code has no space on it !!!

Comment: @user3391995 Then tell me: WHAT is not working. Just saying it's not working isn't helpful. We don't know what this 'IT' is.

Comment: sorry
^_^
 
All images in my HTML page are showing as broken links in FireFox and they are fine in other browsers

Comment: Please add this important information to your question.

Comment: When I contact the support they said it is known issue with CSS